# Issues plotting subplots in a specified number of rows and columns

Tags: subplot, enumerate

So I'm trying to plot all the columns in the 'freq_cols' dataset using subplots in rows and columns. However, the plots display only the last column in all the boxes rather than the individual columns in the dataset. Here is what I have so far. Please advice. Thanks!

```
freq_cols = frequency[['LF','LF_PCT','LF_NU','VLF','VLF_PCT','HF','HF_PCT','HF_NU','HF_LF','TP']]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols = 5, nrows = 2, figsize = (30, 7))
for col_name, col_name in enumerate(freq_cols.columns):
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(5):
            sns.distplot(freq_cols[col_name], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[i, j])
```

[Click this link to see a screenshot of the desired plot(top row) vs what I get(bottom row)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7HCe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just guesstimating the problem.

You have written col_name twice

```py
for col_name, col_name in enumerate(freq_cols.columns):
```

may be you want to write

```py
for col_num, col_name in enumerate(freq_cols.columns):
```

Perhaps below might work

```py
freq_cols = frequency[['LF','LF_PCT','LF_NU','VLF','VLF_PCT','HF','HF_PCT','HF_NU','HF_LF','TP']]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols = 5, nrows = 2, figsize = (30, 7))
for col_num, col_name in enumerate(freq_cols.columns):
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(5):
            sns.distplot(freq_cols[col_name], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[i, j])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try the code above and it still returns the same plot in all the windows. Same as the screenshot in the problem statement.